# Give an initial guess to the quadratic programming solver of CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal, quadratic-programming

I want to solve an overdetermined system of the form Ax=b and in the same time bound the x vector. 
For this I’ve used the quadratic programming library of CGAL, however, I wonder if there is a way to give to the solver
an initial guess `x0` for the solution, since I have a working set and I want to optimize it.